# how to select of displaty of one select box options is selected , then i need to show second select box

Tags: cakephp

here i pasted code for select box

```
echo $this->Form->input('accounttype', array(
    'options' => array('Doctor','Patient') //here 0 means doctor 1 means patient
    ));
```

here if here i selected one option **Doctors**
then only the second select box should be show, other wise it won't ..

```
if($user['accouttype']== 0){
        echo $this->Form->input('specality', array(
    'options' => array('Anesthesiologist','Emergency medicine','Family medicin','General surgery') //here 0 means doctor 1 means patient
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using AJAX and boils down to some jQuery and a little bit of Cake.

Take a look at
http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/
which explains how you can leverage Cake here in a clean way.

It also has a live working example code in the sandbox:
[chained dropdowns](http://sandbox.dereuromark.de/sandbox/ajax_examples/chained_dropdowns) - code [here](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-sandbox/blob/master/Plugin/Sandbox/Controller/AjaxExamplesController.php).